# Carry forward / Bring forward balance in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, window-functions, mysql-8.0

I have created a table as below:

```
Member_ID | Amount | BringForward | Balance | DateTime
101         -100                              2020-08-01 13:12:02.113
101         -200                              2020-08-01 14:15:23.115
101          300                              2020-08-02 10:25:15.315
101          500                              2020-08-05 08:47:56.286
```

I want to add the data for the BringForward and Balance, BringForward will carry forward the total amount from previous day (If the date is 1 Aug, it will get all the total sum of amount from the first day of data to 31 July). Balance is BringForward - Amount.

What I expect is:

```
Member_ID | Amount | BringForward | Balance | DateTime
101         -100     0              100       2020-08-01 13:12:02.113
101         -200     0              200       2020-08-01 14:15:23.115
101          300     -300           0         2020-08-02 10:25:15.315
101          500     0             -500      2020-08-05 08:47:56.286
```

What I've tried is:

```
select MP.MEMBER_ID AS Member_ID, 
CONCAT(MP.AMT_TXN , MP.AMT_TXN_EX) AS Amount, 
sum(cast(concat(AMT_TXN,amt_txn_ex) as decimal)) over (order by mp.create_date) AS BringForward, 
(sum(cast(concat(AMT_TXN,amt_txn_ex) as decimal)) over (order by mp.create_date) - CONCAT(MP.AMT_TXN , MP.AMT_TXN_EX))  AS Balance, 
MP.CREATE_DATE AS DateTime
from MEMBER_TRANSFER MP
```

The result is:

```
Member_ID | Amount | BringForward | Balance | DateTime
101         -100     -100           0         2020-08-01 13:12:02.113
101         -200     -300          -100       2020-08-01 14:15:23.115
101          300      100          -200       2020-08-02 10:25:15.315
101          500      800           300       2020-08-05 08:47:56.286
```

MEMBER_TRANSFER table:

```
MEMBER_ID | AMT_TXN | AMT_TXN_EX | CREATE_DATE
101                   -100         2020-08-01 13:12:02.113
101                   -200         2020-08-01 14:15:23.115
101         300                    2020-08-02 10:25:15.315
101         500                    2020-08-05 08:47:56.286
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions and a range specification:

```
select
    member_id,
    amount,
    coalesce(sum(coalesce(amt_txn, 0) + coalesce(amt_txn_ex, 0)) over(
        partition by member_id
        order by datetime 
        range between unbounded preceding and interval 1 day preceding
    ), 0) bringforward,
    coalesce(sum((coalesce(amt_txn, 0) + coalesce(amt_txn_ex, 0)) over(
        partition by member_id
        order by datetime range between unbounded preceding and interval 1 day preceding
    ), 0) - (coalesce(amt_txn, 0) - coalesce(amt_txn_ex, 0) balance 
from member_transfer m
```

Comment: There is an error which is Incorrect syntax near 'interval'. (Red underline appear under the word 'interval') Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Mouris: did you try to run the query? Which error are you getting exactly?